# Line comment format in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, comments

Is there a way to **remove** the **space** inserted after the line comment character(s), and to start the comment at the **start of the line** in Visual Studio Code? (thus being able to use the commented-out-code comment style)

Before:

```cpp
void fn() {
    code();
}
```

After (applying `Toggle Line Comment` command):

```cpp
void fn() {
    // code();
}
```

Desired:

```cpp
void fn() {
//    code();
}
```

I would prefer either a global switch or a per language configuration.

E.g. in *Sublime Text 3* you can achieve this by copying the `Comments.tmPreferences` file from the package of a given language to into the user packages, and changing the value of the `TM_COMMENT_START` and `TM_COMMENT_DISABLE_INDENT` settings shell variables. E.g. the original `Groovy.sublime-package\Comments.tmPreferences`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comments</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>source.groovy</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>shellVariables</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>name</key>
                <string>TM_COMMENT_START</string>
                <key>value</key>
                <string>// </string>
            </dict>
...
```

On the other hand in *Visual Studio Code* in the `language-configuration.json` file of a given language the `comments.lineComment` values already lack the extra space, so they are inserted somewhere else. E.g. the original `groovy\language-configuration.json`:

```
{
    "comments": {
        "lineComment": "//",
        "blockComment": [ "/*", "*/" ]
    },
...
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what you're talking about in context?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418108/make-comments-of-vscode-start-at-column-position-0/59448448#59448448 (make comments start at column 0).  It may be helpful.