# Make comments of VSCode start at column position 0

Tags: comments, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, when I press the key combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, VSCode will comment the selected lines, ensuring indentation is intact. So if a line of code starts at position 16, then the double slashes of comment (i.e., `//`) will be at position 16, shifting the code to the right a little.

I would like to set it, so that when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>, the comment double slashes `//` will always start at column position 0. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: What language(s) do you want this for?

Comment: @Mark - I prefer a generic solution for all editors. However, I am using it for JavaScript and PHP

Comment: @Greeso I'm glad I'm not the only one who sees the benefits of this kind of comment indentation! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a later and better way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72311327/836330

---

It is a little tricky, but test this out.  You need a macro extension like [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command).

In your keybindings.json:

```
 {                   // disable ctrl+/ for js/php files only
   "key": "ctrl+/",
   "command": "-editor.action.commentLine",
   "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(js$|php)/"
 },

{                   // call the macro multiCommand.insertCommentColumn0 when
                     // commenting a single line
  "key": "ctrl+/",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.insertCommentColumn0" },
  "when": "!editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(js$|php)/" 
},      

{                    // call the macro multiCommand.AddCommentColumn0MultipleLines when
                     // commenting more than one line
  "key": "ctrl+/",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": { "command": "multiCommand.AddCommentColumn0MultipleLines" },
  "when": "editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(js$|php)/" 
},

 {                   // call the command editor.action.removeCommentLine when
                     // commenting a single or multiple line(s)
   "key": "ctrl+shift+/",
   "command": "editor.action.removeCommentLine",
   "when": "!editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(js$|php)/"
 },
```

---

In your settings.json, the macros:

```
"multiCommand.commands": [

  {
    "command": "multiCommand.insertCommentColumn0",
    "sequence": [
      "cursorLineStart",
      {
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
          "text": "// "
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.AddCommentColumn0MultipleLines",
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",        
      "cursorLineStart",
      {
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
          "text": "// "
        }
      },
      "removeSecondaryCursors"
    ]
  },
```

---

This `resourceExtname =~ /\\.(js$|php)/` restricts the keybindings to `.js` and `.php` files (and not `.json` files).  You can change that if you want the keybindings to apply to more file types.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to apply the comment characters at column position 0 and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to remove the comment characters.

You can change those keys to whatever you want.  Note it isn't (and currently cannot be) a simple toggle using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> - with a keybinding there is no way to detect whether a comment already exists.  You would need an extension to get that kind of functionality.

[image: demo of inserting comments at column zero]

---

One downside of this method is that if you select multiple lines and comment them, you will lose that mult-line selection (as can be seen in the demo).

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles here, the accepted solution is fantastic, and I'd like to expand on it. This modification preserves selection, adds `.c` and `.cpp` files, as well as being able to toggle comments in `.py` and `.sh`. Other comment types and file extensions can easily be added.

Note that I prefer `//` to `//`  (without the trailing backspace). Feel free to modify to your liking.

keybindings.json

```
{
                    // call the macro multiCommand.insertCppCommentColumn0 when
                    // commenting a single or multiple line(s)
    "key": "ctrl+/",
    "command": "multiCommand.insertCppCommentColumn0",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(js$|php$|c$|cpp$|json)/" 
},

{                   // call the macro multiCommand.insertPyCommentColumn0 when
                    // commenting a single or multiple line(s)
    "key": "ctrl+/",
    "command": "multiCommand.insertPyCommentColumn0",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(py$|sh)/" 
},

{                   // call the command editor.action.removeCommentLine when
                    // commenting a single or multiple line(s)
    "key": "ctrl+shift+/",
    "command": "editor.action.removeCommentLine",
    "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly && resourceExtname =~ /\\.(js$|php$|c$|cpp$|json$|py$|sh)/"
},
```

settings.json

```
  "multiCommand.commands": [
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.insertCppCommentColumn0",
    "description": "Toggle Comments (c/c++/json/js/php)",
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.setSelectionAnchor",
      "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",        
      "cursorLineStart",
      {
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
          "text": "//"
        }
      },
      "removeSecondaryCursors",
      "editor.action.selectFromAnchorToCursor"
    ]
  },
  {
    "command": "multiCommand.insertPyCommentColumn0",
    "description": "Toggle Comments (py/sh)",
    "sequence": [
      "editor.action.setSelectionAnchor",
      "editor.action.insertCursorAtEndOfEachLineSelected",        
      "cursorLineStart",
      {
        "command": "type",
        "args": {
          "text": "#"
        }
      },
      "removeSecondaryCursors",
      "editor.action.selectFromAnchorToCursor"
    ]
  }
]
```