# Is there a way to disable auto-indenting only on comments in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, comments

I want to keep my formatting settings, but have them not affect comments in my code. Can I apply such a setting  in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: What language are you wanting to disable auto-indentation of comments for?

Comment: You should show an example of what you want to do.  Comment indicators flush left or something else?  One of these:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673112/vscode-preserve-indentation-when-commenting-out-lines/60677277#60677277 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418108/make-comments-of-vscode-start-at-column-position-0/59448448#59448448 I don't believe there is a built-in way to do it (but I would need to see exactly what you are asking).