# How to comment out code in VS Code without indent?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Currently, after commenting out the code (e.g. in BASH script) in VS Code I get:

```bash
function foo {

    #function bar {
    #    echo 'Le Bar.';
    #}
}
```

but I'd like to have this:

```bash
function foo {

#    function bar {
#        echo 'Le Bar.';
#    }
}
```

I can't find proper settings for disabling comment indentation, what am I missing?

**Edit**: I created **Feature Request** for it, please upvote, if you're also interested in having it here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147168 — just 20 upvotes will move the request to backlog. :-)

**Edit**: "Just" 15 votes more and we gonna have it! (Well, almost) :-) Please be so kind to upvote! :-)

**Edit**: **Just** 2 votes more! :-) Speak up! Don't be shy! :-)

Comment: Are these similar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673112/vscode-preserve-indentation-when-commenting-out-lines/60677277#60677277, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418108/make-comments-of-vscode-start-at-column-position-0/59448448#59448448)?

Comment: @ArnavThorat Thanks for these, but it seems like huge overkill. I really hoped for something within VS itself.

Comment: Hmm... I don't think there's a feature like that. 

Comment: @ArnavThorat Knowing that something is unavailable is still appreciated, as at least I can quit poking around—hence +1 for it! Thanx! :-)

Comment: I know it's a bit late, but I've upvoted  your GitHub Issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no features built into Visual Studio Code for not indenting comments.

However, if you *really* want to have them, you could follow these two links to other Stack Overflow answers (but it might just be overkill):

- [VSCode Preserve Indentation when Commenting out Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673112/vscode-preserve-indentation-when-commenting-out-lines/60677277#60677277)
- [Make Comments of VSCode Start at Column Position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418108/make-comments-of-vscode-start-at-column-position-0/59448448#59448448)

You can also make a GitHub Issue on Microsoft's [official Visual Studio Code repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) with the tag `feature-request`.

---

In summary, there isn't a feature like that in Visual Studio Code. However, there are a few solutions, but they just might be overkill for such a simple task.

Comment: Feature requested under https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147168, votes are appreciated. :-)

Comment: I upvoted the issue despite the magnificent work done on those two SO questions linked in the answer ;>}