# How to control the comment bars // in VS Code

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio-code, comments, vscode-extensions

I´m used to Eclipse, where when you press Ctrl+Shift+C it add two bars to the most left side of the file but keep your indentation (I´m using the Eclipse Keymaps extension for using Eclipse shortcuts), for example:

//Comment here
fn main() {

//    Comment here
println!("Hello Stackoverflow!");

//        Imagine more indentation here

}

On VS Code comments are handled like this:
//Comment here
fn main() {

```
  //Comment here
  println!("Hello Stackoverflow!");

      //Imagine more indentation here
```

}

I don´t like it and it´s a deal breaker for me, I love the editor otherwise.
Is there a way to change this?

I tried a couple of extension for customizing comments and playing around with the settings, but nothing worked for me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Here is a way to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72311327/836330

Comment: The `vscode-extension` tag is just for extension development, not for your case.  That is why it was removed by another editor.